# Why would the vars in these functions fail to calculate?

Tags: javascript

I know this is a rookie question so forgive me but can anyone tell me why these two functions would fail to compute. (I had paid someone to do it but I'm starting to think they had as much of a clue as me)

This function should calculate the amount commission is due on by subtracting target from nettakings.

```
            $(function(){
            $("#Commissionon").keyup(function(){
                var target = $("#target_").val();
                var nettakings = $("#nettakings_").val();
                //alert(targetmultiplier);
                $("#Commissionon_").html();
                $("#Commissionon_").html(nettakings-target);
            })
          })
```

This function should return the % that a user types in a cell which should then calculate an amount to another cell as the amount due of the function above. ie if above totalled 100 and user types 50% the amount would show as £50 commission. (% sign can be outside the cell)

```
  $(function(){
    $("#Commissionp").keyup(function(){
        var Commissionp = $("#Commissionp").val();
        //alert(Commissionp);
        $("#Commissionp_").html();
        $("#Commissionp_").html(Commissionp);
```

Full code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#Hourlyrate").keyup(function() {
    var Hoursworked = $("#Hoursworked").val();
    //alert(Hoursworked);
    var Hourlyrate = $("#Hourlyrate").val();
    $("#Basepay_").html();
    $("#Basepay_").html(Hoursworked * Hourlyrate);
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#Targetmultiplier").keyup(function() {
    var targetmultiplier = $("#Targetmultiplier").val();
    //alert(targetmultiplier);
    var Basepay = $("#Basepay_").html();
    $("#target_").html();
    $("#target_").html(targetmultiplier * Basepay * 1.2);
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#Grosstakings").keyup(function() {
    var nettakings = $("#Grosstakings").val();
    //alert(targetmultiplier);
    $("#nettakings_").html();
    $("#nettakings_").html(nettakings / 1.2);
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#Commissionon").keyup(function() {
    var Commissionon = $("#Commissionon").val();
    var target = $("#target_").html();
    var nettakings = $("#nettakings_").html();
    //alert(targetmultiplier);
    $("#Commissionon_").html();
    $("#Commissionon_").html(nettakings - target);
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#Commissionp").keyup(function() {
    var Commissionp = $("#Commissionp").val();
    //alert(Commissionp);
    $("#Commissionp_").html();
    $("#Commissionp_").html(Commissionp);
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#Commission").keyup(function() {
    var Commissionon = $("#Commissionon").val();
    //alert(Hoursworked);
    var Commissionp = $("#Commissionp").val();
    $("#Commission_").html();
    $("#Commission_").html(Commissionon * Commissionp);
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#Wage").keyup(function() {
    var basepay = $("#Basepay_").html();
    //alert(Hoursworked);
    var Commission = $("#Commission").val();
    $("#Wage_").html();
    $("#Wage_").html(basepay + Commission);
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#Holidayaccrued").keyup(function() {
    var Hourlyrate = $("#Hourlyrate").val();
    // alert(Hourlyrate);
    var Hoursworked = $("#Hoursworked").val();
    $("#Holidayaccrued_").html();
    $("#Holidayaccrued_").html(((12.07 / 100) * Hoursworked) * Hourlyrate);
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#emppensionp").keyup(function() {
    var emppensionp = $("#emppensionp").val();
    //alert(Hoursworked);
    $("#emppensionp_").html();
    $("#emppensionp_").html(emppensionp);
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#Emppension").keyup(function() {
    var Emppension = $("#Emppension").val();
    //alert(Hoursworked);
    var Wage = $("#Wage").val();
    $("#Emppension_").html();
    $("#Emppension_").html((Emppension * Wage));
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#Employerni").keyup(function() {
    var Employerni = $("#Employerni").val();
    //alert(Hoursworked);
    var Wage = $("#Wage").val();
    $("#Employerni_").html();
    $("#Employerni_").html(((Wage * 13.8) / 100));
  })
})
$(function() {
  $("#totalpayroll").keyup(function() {
    var totalpayroll = $("#totalpayroll").val();
    //alert(Hoursworked);
    var Wage = $("#Wage").val();
    var Employerni = $("#Employerni").val();
    var Holidayaccrued = $("#Holidayaccrued").val();
    var emppension = $("#emppension").val();
    $("#totalpayroll_").html();
    $("#totalpayroll_").html(Wage + Employerni + Holidayaccrued + emppension);
  })
})
```

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: 60%;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #800080;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!--script src='scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <!--script src='scripts/globalize.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='scripts/sessvars.js' type='text/javascript'></script--> 

<h1>Calculate Commission and Total Payroll Cost.</h1>
<p>Calculate Commission and Total Payroll Cost.</p>
<hr>
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"><label for="Hoursworked"><b>Hours Worked</b></label></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"><input type="number" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Hours Worked" name="Hoursworked" id="Hoursworked" required></div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"><label for="Hourlyrate"><b>Hourly Rate</b></label></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"><input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Enter Hourly Rate" id="Hourlyrate" name="Hourlyrate" required></div>
      <div class="divTableCell" id="Basepay_">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"><label for="Targetmultiplier"><b>Target Multiplier</b></label></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"><input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Enter Target Multiplier" name="Targetmultiplier" id="Targetmultiplier" required></div>
      <div class="divTableCell" id="target_">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"><label for="Grosstakings"><b>Actual Gross Takings</b></label></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"><input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Enter Gross Takings" name="Grosstakings" id="Grosstakings" required></div>
      <div class="divTableCell" id="Grosstakings_">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell" id="nettakings_">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"><label for="Commissionon"><b>Commission On</b></label></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"><input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="" name="Commissionon" id="Commissionon" required></div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell" id="Commissionon_"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"><label for="Commissionp"><b>Commission %</b></label></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"><input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Enter Commission %" name="Commission" id="Commissionp" required></div>
      <div class="divTableCell" id="Commissionp_">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell"><label for="Commission"><b>Commission</b></label></div>
      <div class="divTableCell"><input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="" name="Commission" id="Commission" required></div>
      <div class="divTableCell" id="Commission_"></div>
      <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell"><label for="Wage"><b>Wage</b></label></div>
    <div class="divTableCell"><input class="form-control" id="Wage" type="number" placeholder="" name="Wage" required></div>
    <div class="divTableCell" id="Wage_">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell"><label for="Holidayaccrued"><b>Holiday Pay Accrued</b></label></div>
    <div class="divTableCell"><input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="" id="Holidayaccrued" name="Holidayaccrued" required></div>
    <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divTableCell" id="Holidayaccrued_">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell"><label for="emppensionp"><b>Emp Pension Contribution %</b></label></div>
    <div class="divTableCell"><input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="" name="emppensionp" id="emppensionp" required></div>
    <div class="divTableCell" id="emppensionp_">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell"><label for="Emppension"><b>Employers Pension Contribution</b></label></div>
    <div class="divTableCell"><input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="" name="Emppension" id="Emppension" required></div>
    <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divTableCell" id="Emppension_">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell"><label for="Employerni"><b>Employer N.I.</b></label></div>
    <div class="divTableCell"><input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="" name="Employerni" id="Employerni" required>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divTableCell" id="Employerni_">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell"><label for="totalpayroll"><b>Total Payroll Cost</b></label></div>
    <div class="divTableCell"><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="totalpayroll" id="totalpayroll" required></div>

    <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="divTableCell" id="totalpayroll_">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is failing, what's the issue?

Comment: paying someone to receive jquery code..brutal

Comment: Thanks Ashish, the 1st one does nothing and the 2nd on inserts the same number the user types in to the answer cell ie cell1 30% function inserts 30 in cell2 when it should be 30% of the amount generated by the first function in cell2,

Comment: @sanchez,  I normally do stuff in Excel and knew converting it to tables on the web was beyond my knowledge which only extended to Frontpage and then ecomm software.
Nothing on Fiverr ever ends up costing a fiver. it seems.

Comment: Frontpage! Takes me back :). `val()` returns a string; put a `+` before the `$("` to coerce to a number. You don't need the empty `.html()` that *returns* the HTML, it doesn't set it, and since you're setting it in the next line, you don't need to set it to nothing first.

Comment: @HereticMonkey While it's a good idea to convert to a number first, the `-` operator will do this automatically.

Comment: Why is the event handler in the first example attached to a different element than the ones containing the values that you want to subtract?

Comment: You need to post a **minimal** example, including the HTML. The code posted doesn't do what you want it to do, and the related elements that it needs to get information (*…calculate an amount to another cell*) from aren't shown.

Comment: @Barmar, I'm not sure to be honest, all of the code looks weird to me. Is there a way to attach a pic here?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Hopefully this is ok, if not please let me know and I will delete. 
For some reason ctr+K fails to work for me so I have put the whole code here if you can help me that way? http://plnkr.co/edit/9s3h6zMavar5bXh1?open=lib%2Fscript.js 
This is what the calculator originally looked like https://www.salonlogic.co.uk/forms/Commission/Commission.php (this was built using a form builder but had issues in that I couldn't edit their code to make a negative answer show as 0.
and this is what I ended up with https://www.salonlogic.co.uk/test.php

Comment: jQuery's `val()` returns a string. Try to convert them like:
`var target = parseFloat($("#target_").val());    
var nettakings = parseFloat($("#nettakings_").val());`

Comment: @KubwimanaAdrien Thanks but no joy with your suggestion either. :-(

Comment: @Barmar was the way I linked to the code any use? :-)

Comment: Did you read the Stack Snippet documentation? That's the best way to provide the code.

Comment: BTW, you don't have to keep using `$(function...)` all over the code. Just put that around the whole block.

Comment: The `index.html` at the external link doesn't have any of the input elements that you're targeting in the JS.

Comment: @Barmar   Thanks for getting back to me. :-) Apologies, I have now posted the whole page code here  http://plnkr.co/edit/8Dld8ePEsvUvo9Nn?open=lib%2Fscript.js  I did look at the Stack Snippet information but am unsure where the error is happening to post it. I have managed to partly get the first calculation to work by deleting the scripts which referred back to the old form elements.

Comment: You mentioned Ctl-k, but you don't use that when creating a stack snippet.

Comment: You shouldn't have HTML and CSS in `script.js`

Comment: You're loading two versions of jQuery, that will cause problems.

Comment: never mind, one of them is commented out.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks. I think I am going to have to scrap the code and start again as I just can't get it to work and when I ran it through through a javascript checker and there were more errors than I thought possible. Also when I deleted the $(function...) as you suggested everything stopped working.

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys, the issues were all to do with the way the the code from a form builder worked and my trying to convert them to a new environment. All sorted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several problems with your code:

1) You should be using onchange instead of keyup, as the form doesn't work when you using the html5 input buttons to change values.

2) completely unnecessary to do calls like this: $("#emppensionp_").html();

3) variables should start with lowercase letter

4) you need to either default all your input values to '0' or have code to handle undefined values.